Access, running sumifs
I have a MS Access table, which looks like that

I've stated the desired result in a separate column: the running sumif for the product column to summarize the earlier QTY.
On the every type of a product it summarizes the earlier QTY that specific product in the current table had. Above the current row.
I tried standard Access options, but it looks like SQL is needed there and I have no idea about SQL code.

I've managed to find a solution and it should looks like that
SELECT T1.CatNo, T1.ID, T1.QtyI, T1.Cons, (SELECT SUM(QtyI) FROM OO_T WHERE T1.ID > ID AND T1.Cons = Cons) AS Running
FROM OO_T AS T1;
